# How to turn on autocomplete for frameworks [Notepad++]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, autocomplete, notepad++

I'm using the D3.js framework to create some visualizations. ALthough I do have autocomplete activated it won't show me potential functions of the D3 framework. E.g. when I type "D3.svg." now it should show me at least a bunch of keywords that could follow after "svg.". Does autocomplete only work for Javascript and self-defined functions? It also doesn't seem to work for objects, like arrays.
 array.m (should be completed to array.map e.g.)

Is there a solution for that? Are other editors/IDEs capable of doing this? Specifically I'm looking for a lightweight editor/IDE that is opened quickly and supports many languages.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not to *turn on* autocomplete for a framework. The problem is having that framework's auto-completion rules installed on notebook++. It has to be a XML file. Please, have a look at this:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion

The good news is that it's possible to find these files for JS libraries, as this one for JQuery:
http://jamesallardice.com/jquery-code-hinting-in-notepad/

The bad news is that I was unable to find one for D3. But maybe, if this is a useful feature for you, you can create it yourself!